# Home directory Postgresql in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3

I installed postgresql 9.3 using terminal in my ubuntu 14.04 by

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

My postgresql is running, but I can't find its home directory. Some tutorial says that home directory located in /usr/local/pgsql, but I can't find mine. I've been searching for a week, and found nothing.

And what directory I should use if I wanna set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` you will probably want to add this path globally, by creating *.conf file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` (I use oracle client library path for example):

```
$ echo '/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/' | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
```

then you need to rebuild library cache and restart postgres:

```
$ sudo ldconfig
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```

And the home is in `/var/lib/postgresql`. All users homes are set up in `/etc/passwd` file:

```
$ grep postgres /etc/passwd
postgres:x:116:125:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
```